# Extending javascript global built-ins with React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Been searching the web to find something like this, but haven't had any success so far. I frequently find myself accidentally using Array.includes in React, only to later remember that IE doesn't support Array.includes.

Ideally, I'd like to do something like

```
if (!Array.includes){
    Array.prototype.includes = (val) => { return this.indexOf(val) !== -1); }
}
```

However getting this to work in the React system hasn't proved fruitful. Does anyone have ideas/experience on how to get something like this working?

I've currently came up with a workaround, but I really would like to focus this on the point of modifying global built-ins.

*Extra details: using Webpack with ES2016 syntax, React + Redux*

Comment: Checkout babel polyfills https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/

Comment: *"However getting this to work in the React system hasn't proved fruitful."* It shouldn't make a difference if you use React or not. You just have to put this part at the beginning of all your code.

Comment: @EPICmynamesbg did you voluntarily remove your answer? Because now, this question will just linger instead of beign "resolved". It would be much better with your self answer being accepted.

Comment: Just add an Array.includes polyfill in your top level JS file

Comment: @realseanp yeah, OP did manage to do that, self answered so that we don't try and answer the question over and over again, but apparently some people were intent on deleting that answer. They did, indeed, use polyfill.

Comment: Looks like a moderator removed my answer. I did forget to mark it as correct. I would if I could now... The answer was using Polyfill